# Animating a single candlestick

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to produce 5 candlesticks.
Seconds next to it minutes, hours, day, week, month. 
Id like the candlestick self to update based on its time frame

Witch library or method would be suggested

At the moment I'm using `plotly` but it's giving me time-based charts and not single candle animations

As a Base, I'm using the default code provided in the `plotly` documentation

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from datetime import datetime

open_data = [2, 4, 2, 2, 6]
high_data = [3, 4, 1, 4, 6]
low_data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
close_data = [2, 2, 1, 3, 2]
dates = [datetime(2018-10-29 23:00:01)]

trace = go.Candlestick(x=dates,
                       open=open_data,
                       high=high_data,
                       low=low_data,
                       close=close_data)
data = [trace]
py.offline.plot(data, filename='candlestick_datetime')
```

and have it produces a single candle now all I want is for it to go through each array and update the candle with the next value

Comment: Thank shivam bhatnagar English is not my 1st language